# Spring Boot Error 404 Not Found Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, postman

I am new to Spring Boot and I am just trying to get/fetch data from datasource through this code :

> EmployeController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")

    public class EmployeController {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeService employeService;

        @GetMapping("/employe")
        public List<Employe> get(){
            return employeService.get();
        }
    }
```

> Employe.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employe")
public class Employe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String gender;
    @Column
    private String department;
    @Column
    private Date dob;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employe [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", department=" + department + ", dob="
                + dob + "]";
    }
```

> EmployeService.java

```
public interface EmployeService {
    List<Employe> get();
    Employe get(int id);
    void save(Employe employe);
    void delete(int id);
}
```

> EmployeServiceImplement.java

```
@Service
public class EmployeServiceImplement implements EmployeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeDAO employeDAO;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<Employe> get() {
        return employeDAO.get();
    }
}
```

> EmployeDAO.java

```
public interface EmployeDAO {
    List<Employe> get();
    Employe get(int id);
    void save(Employe employe);
    void delete(int id);
}
```

> EmployeDAOimplement.java

```
@Repository
public class EmployeDAOImplement implements EmployeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Employe> get() {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<Employe> query = currentSession.createQuery("from Employe", Employe.class);
        List<Employe>list = query.getResultList();  
        return list;
    }
}
```

I have writen all the configuration related to MySQl database into the application.properties and created a employe table into my database.

As i know that  Spring Data JPA is much better way to implement than this but as i m just want to begin with the same ... As running my project as Spring Boot App and then from Postman i am getting the 404 Error like this :

[image]

I am unable to understand why this is showing the 404 error and how to solve it..

Comment: could you please edit to post your spring boot main application class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it like this:

Set in your application props file:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

Then remove RequestMapping Annotation:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeService employeService;

    @GetMapping("/employe")
    public List<Employe> get(){
        return employeService.get();
     }
 }
```

Then you should be able to retrieve it with requeste URL

Comment: after applying server.servlet.context-path=/api is it necessary to remove the Mapping Annotaion

Comment: Yes, you can remove the Annotation as stated in the answer. Otherwise the endpoint would look like this: "api/api/employe"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the name of your artifact (project name) in the request URI. Ex:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/api/employe
```

If you dont want it in the URI, change the contextPath configuration in your application.properties:

```
server.contextPath = /
```

Answer (score 1):

The annotation on your controller `@RequestMapping("/api")` means the route will be `http://localhost:8080/api` but you're trying to invoke `http://localhost:8080/api/employe`. I think you should just change it to `@RequestMapping("/api/employe")`.

Answer (score 1):

What is your context path configuration in application.properties? You'll see a property  same as this `server.servlet.context-path` only if you set it. If you didn't set it, then probably the path `http://localhost:8080/api/employe` is correct, in that case I'll suggest checking if your application really running on port `8080`, if some other application runs on port `8080` and your application runs on some other port then you'll surely get a 404 response.